# Precompiled Tensorflow is faster than TF built from the source CPU optimized, how to reproduce precompiled?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, performance-testing, precompiled-binaries

I have a trained tensorflow.keras model. I'm loading my model and doing inference from my C code on CPU on Ubuntu 18.04. For performance reasons, I'm comparing different builts of Tensorflow.

The first built I have is the precompiled version that I downloaded from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c.

> https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-linux-x86_64-2.4.0.tar.gz

Then I built the tensorflow 2.4 from the source following the installation procedure [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). I used the defaults in  ./configure. Then I ran,

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow
```

Then I untar the generated file below and do the necessary exports (I didn't untar into /usr/local),

> ~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/libtensorflow.tar.gz

Lastly, I rebuilt the tensorflow 2.4 from the source, again used the defaults in ./configure. Then I ran,

```
bazel build --config=mkl --config=noaws --config=nogcp --config=nohdfs -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow
```

From what I read, this command should build tensorflow with intel-mkl support and with avx, avx2, fma, sse4.1 and sse4.2 instruction sets. I checked that my CPU supports those instructions. Then I untar the generated file and did the exports.

The performance results show that precompiled library is nearly twice as fast than the ones I built from the source. What am I doing wrong here, I couldn't find any other way other than using

```
--config=mkl -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2
```

Building with these options didn't show any change in performance. Is there a way to learn with which flags the precompiled versions were built, how can I reproduce it?

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm, try building to native, --arch=native I think, instead of the the --copt=-msse4.1 and 4.2.

Comment: @Surt Should I use the following flags then,
`--config=mkl --config=noaws --config=nogcp --config=nohdfs --config=-march=native`?

Comment: That might be the most optimal, if your going to run it on your PC, else you have to specify the target architecture.